# Hide the control bar while playing video

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I have created application using android phonegap. I want to play a video in the android phone without showing the Control bars.
   So I used  Video player plugin in Phonegap for playing video and the video plays on onclick but I couldn't hide the control bar. Is there any way to remove/hide the video control bars?

Comment: are you using videoView??

Comment: No, I am not using videoView.I am playing video using intent Intent intent = null; intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType("http://XXX", "video/*");

Answer (score 1):

Instead going for android native plugin, html 5 or phonegap plugin can be used to show the video and also it has option to hide and show the control bar.

I have used video.js plugin with which you can play the video and also can control the control bar. I have provided the link for video.js

http://blog.videojs.com/post/57828375480/hiding-and-showing-video-player-controls

And also in this they have control to hide and show the control bar when the mouse moves out and comes back to the screen. As this is a mobile , i will give suggestion to do this.

Below is the code to hide the control bar in video.js

```
controlBar.addClass('vjs-fade-out');
```

Below is the code to show the control bar in video.js

```
controlBar.removeClass('vjs-fade-out');
```

You can hide the control panel after the person has not touched the mobile and show the control panel when he touches it. Now you have the way to hide and show the control bar of the video player and so you have to think of logic to use it effectively.